# aws policy for ec2:RunInstances with multiple conditions result in rejected request

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-policies

I want to be able to restrict `ec2:*` operations (specifically **ec2:RunInstances**) only in a specific AWS account and prevent them against existing ec2 instances having a dedicated tag.

I have the following policy:

```json
{
            "Sid": "EC2InfraAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:ResourceAccount": [
                        "111111111111"
                    ]
                },
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:ResourceTag/cluster": [
                        "team-prod-eks",
                        "team-stage-eks"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
```

So I want the user to be able to perform `ec2:RunInstances` but have no ability to perform any `ec2:*` actions against nodes of two kubernetes clusters.

The resources in the account `111111111111` do have tags `cluster=team-prod-eks` or `cluster=team-stage-eks`.

I need the user to be able to create new **ec2** instances without ability to perform any ops against the nodes associated with these 2 eks clusters.

But it doesn't work and I receive:

```
Error: creating EC2 instance: UnauthorizedOperation: 
You are not authorized to perform this operation. Encoded authorization failure message....
```

The decoded message has this:

```json
{
    "allowed": false,
    "explicitDeny": false,
    "matchedStatements": {
        "items": []
    },
    "failures": {
        "items": []
    },
    "context": {
        "principal": {
            "id": "AROA6BMT6GMYSAV3BDPVI:UserName",
            "arn": "arn:aws:sts::111111111:assumed-role/AWSReservedSSO_role_5fbf1098ce7e652e/UserName"
        },
        "action": "ec2:RunInstances",
        "resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2::image/ami-0c12b5d624d73f1c0",
        "conditions": {
            "items": [
                {
                    "key": "ec2:ImageID",
                    "values": {
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "value": "ami-0c12b5d624d73f1c0"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "ec2:ImageType",
                    "values": {
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "value": "machine"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "aws:Resource",
                    "values": {
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "value": "image/ami-0c12b5d624d73f1c0"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "aws:Account",
                    "values": {
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "value": "801119661308"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "ec2:IsLaunchTemplateResource",
                    "values": {
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "value": "false"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "ec2:RootDeviceType",
                    "values": {
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "value": "ebs"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "aws:Region",
                    "values": {
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "value": "us-west-2"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "aws:Service",
                    "values": {
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "value": "ec2"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "ec2:Owner",
                    "values": {
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "value": "amazon"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "ec2:Public",
                    "values": {
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "value": "true"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "aws:Type",
                    "values": {
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "value": "image"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "ec2:Region",
                    "values": {
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "value": "us-west-2"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "aws:ARN",
                    "values": {
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "value": "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2::image/ami-0c12b5d624d73f1c0"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

So how to write a proper policy so they can RunInstances in a specific account with any AMI ID?

```
"action": "ec2:RunInstances",
"resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2::image/ami-0c12b5d624d73f1c0",
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a not equals type of condition add a deny with condition and then add allow all. Deny takes preference over the allow.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowEc2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "DenyEc2onCluster",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEqualsIgnoreCase": {
                "aws:ResourceTag/cluster": [
                        "team-prod-eks",
                        "team-stage-eks"
                    ]    
              },
            }
        }
    ]
}
```